# Renci.SshNet SshStream.Flush() not working

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm getting an exception error since while I'm reading for the last commands on a ShellStream I'm also getting some old outputs even if I flushed the Stream with ShellStream.Flush().

All this is part of a foreach loop:

```
            //Type ls | wc command
            ssh_Shell_Stream.WriteLine(cmd_Ls_Wc);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Prevents the shell from losing the output if it becomes too slow

            string stream = "";
            string[] stream_Last_Cmd_Arr;
            string stream_Last_Cmd;
            string line1;

            // Read with a suitable timeout to avoid hanging
            while ((line1 = ssh_Shell_Stream.ReadLine(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))) != null)
            {
                // Assign the entire command stream to stream string
                stream = stream + line1 + "\n";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            // Retrieve only last command output
            stream_Last_Cmd_Arr = stream.Split('\n');           
            stream_Last_Cmd = stream_Last_Cmd_Arr[stream_Last_Cmd_Arr.Length-2];

            // Converting to int to later determine if there's more than one folder
            int ls_wc_result = Convert.ToInt32(stream_Last_Cmd);
```

During `Convert.ToInt32(stream_Last_Cmd);` after a few loops I'm getting an exception error since the last command doesn't coincide with the "ls | wc -l" I actually need. It's like I'm getting the stream buffer stuck on a "curl" command thrown before the "ls | wc -l" command.

My Stream keep on looking something like this: `"bash$ tail -10000 /xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.log > /tmp/xx\xx.root.log\ncurl -T /xx/xxx.x.log ftp://10.10.10.1:21 --user xxx-xxx:xxxx\nbash$ curl -T /xx/xxx.xx.log ftp://1.1.1.1 --user xxxx\xxx-xxxx:xxxxxx\n  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r100 1447k    0     0  100 1447k      0  36.2M --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 37.2M\n"`

While, standing at the commands I thrown, it should be something like: `"bash$ ls /xxx/xx/xx/ | wc -l\n1\n"`

Anyway I'm sure I already paused the main Thread for enough time before proceeding with the other commands.

Besides everything, maybe the Flush() method is not properly cleaning the stream buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this could be a known bug:

I decided to use the Dispose() method to drop the entire shell and to create a new one at each iteration as a workaround:

```
foreach (string SerialNumber in file_Lines)
                {
                    //Creating our ShellStream
                    var ssh_Shell_Stream = CreateShellStream("checker_Terminal", 80, 80, 1024, 1024, 1024);
                    // Send the command
                    ssh_Shell_Stream.WriteLine(cmd1);

                    //Wait 2 seconds and the type the password
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    ssh_Shell_Stream.WriteLine(cmd2);

                    Thread.Sleep(250);
                    SSH_Class.Extractor(X, Y, ssh_Shell_Stream);
                    Thread.Sleep(250);

                    ssh_Shell_Stream.Dispose();
                }
```